# How can print text file in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-3.0, printing

I have simple text file, and i have to print it using WPF. How can i print this file with specified printer setting(like margin, print on both side).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the file to a FlowDocument, then print that.  The trick is in loading the text into the FlowDocument, See:

http://someblokeontheinternet.blogspot.com/2009/11/printing-contents-of-text-box-or-just.html

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft has introduced a new printing API as part of WPF. You can read more about [Printing and Print System Management on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969772.aspx). You will have to format the text into an XPS document which you can then print. There is [a sample on how to programmatically print XPS files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969772.aspx).